# ssh to fqdn with private aaaa record returns "Undefined error: 0" on ipv4 only internet

Tags: macos, ssh, dns, ipv6

I've set up an yggdrasil network (which is ipv6 only) and things work as expected, i.e. I can `ping6 200::1:2:3:4` and `ssh 200::1:2:3:4` from any network.

I then added a few subdomains with aaaa records only (private range 200:...) to my dns (cloudflare) and this also works fine, unless I'm on an ipv4 only network, then `ssh -6 a.b.xyz` gives me `ssh: connect to host a.b.xyz port 22: Undefined error: 0`.
I can still `ping6 a.b.xyz`, `dig aaaa a.b.xyz` and `ssh 200::1:2:3:4` successfully, but it seems ssh has its own method for resolving fqdns.
Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

For solving this problem, we can create the same SystemConfiguration "service" strucures manually using the scutil command:

First we create the IPv4 part of the service:

```
sam@shiny ~> sudo scutil
> d.init
> d.add Addresses * 10.75.131.2
> d.add DestAddresses * 10.75.131.2
> d.add InterfaceName utun1
> set State:/Network/Service/my_ipv6_tunnel_service/IPv4
> set Setup:/Network/Service/my_ipv6_tunnel_service/IPv4
```

And then we create the IPv6 part:

```
> d.init
> d.add Addresses * fe80::a65e:60ff:fee1:b1bf 2600:3c03::de:d002
> d.add DestAddresses * ::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0:0 ::
> d.add Flags * 0 0
> d.add InterfaceName utun1
> d.add PrefixLength * 64 116
> set State:/Network/Service/my_ipv6_tunnel_service/IPv6
> set Setup:/Network/Service/my_ipv6_tunnel_service/IPv6
> quit
```

Once this is done, the output of scutil --dns (again modulo mdns stuff) changes:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home.munkynet.org
  nameserver[0] : 10.20.4.4
  if_index : 14 (en3)
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home.munkynet.org
  nameserver[0] : 10.20.4.4
  if_index : 14 (en3)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)
```

For full information about this problem, you can proceed to [original answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345539).

Comment: Copy-pasted part from original answer due to moderator deleted answer with one link only.